# The included code stub will read an integer, n, from STDIN. Without using any string methods, try to print 1,2,3,4,...n

Tags: loops, for-loop

The included code stub will read an integer,n , from STDIN.

Without using any string methods, try to print the following:
123....n
Note that "" represents the consecutive values in between.

Example
n=5

Print the string 12345

Input Format

The first line contains an integer n.

Constraints
1<n<151

Print the list of integers from 1 through n as a string, without spaces.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should always tag your questions with a programming language. But, even with a language tag your post is not up to SO standards. Please visit the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: You might also want to read: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 0):

The included code stub will read an integer, , from STDIN.

Without using any string methods, try to print the following:

Note that "" represents the consecutive values in between.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    for a in range(1,n+1):
        print(a, end="")
    print()
```

Comment: I think it will help. I too had the same problem and finally I got to figure out the solution please try it and don't forget to give feedback. Thank You

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**